Natural Log's Property Doesn't Transfer Over
I am trying to rewrite the summation of $\ln(x)$ equation into a continuous function using logarithmic properties. We already know that $\left(\sum_{n=1}^{x}\ln\left(n\right)\right)$ is just equal to $\ln(1) + \ln(2) + \ln(3)...\ln(x)$. My question is why this equation doesn't work, $\ln(x(x+1)/2)$. Since the addition of all ascending log #'s add up to the sum of all those number and then logged, shouldn't this give the same result?

$\ln(a+b) \ne \ln(a) + \ln(b)$

You are practicing magical thinking. It's rare that
$$
f(a+b) = f(a) + f(b).
$$
In fact it works only if $f(x) = cx$ for some constant $c$. Then it is just the distributive law.
You are trying to apply it when $f(x) = \ln(x)$.
The sum of the logarithms of the integers from $1$ to $n$ is in fact the logarithm of $n!$.

Well isn't 1+2+3 == 6 and ln(1)+ln(2)+ln(3) == ln(6)?

Yes. That's a coincidence since $6 = 3!$.

Oh! Wow I really just had just made a small error of not just double checking XD

Relevant.

@J.G. Yes, for a more advanced student.
